# Why is my hat dislocated in the top bar?

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash-2013

It seems the smaller the icon gets the more the hat is dislocated (first only horizontally, then vertically too):

*profile big version* -- *profile small version* -- *top bar*

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Doctor! I've dislocated my hat!

Comment: Misplaced, dislocated... so many words! ;)

Comment: Wow, even *hats* dislike the top bar...

Comment: My question is definitely a duplicate, but the other question doesn't have an answer either.

Comment: That's true, but if you feel that there's more attention necessary for that question, you can offer a bounty (2 days after the question is posted).